# Not able to display altair charts in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, altair

I am not able to display the charts on jupyter notebook. The same code displays on chrome in one laptop but does not work on chrome on other laptop.

I do not see any error or even a empty plot when I execute the code but get **alt.Chart(...)** in the output.

The version of altair and vega etc are same on both the laptops.

Answer (score 3):

For 'altair' version of '4.1.0',
'vega' version of '3.4.0'
just do `alt.renderers.enable('default')` instead of
`alt.renderers.enable('notebook')`

Comment: dont use chart.show(). Use instead chart without calling show() function.

Answer (score 1):

If it works in one notebook and not another, there are a couple possibilities for what is going on:

1. your notebooks are connected to different kernels with different versions of Altair and/or its dependencies installed. Run the following

   ```
   import sys
   print(sys.executable)
   ```

   to see if you're using the same Python executable in your environments. If the results are different, you can use *Kernel -> Change Kernel* in the Jupyter notebook menu to change to a kernel with a working Altair version.
2. If that's not the case, then it is likely that you have inadvertently enabled a different [renderer](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/display_frontends.html#altair-s-renderer-framework) in one of the notebooks, for example by running `alt.renderers.enable('notebook')`. In Altair 4.0, the default renderer should work out-of-the-box in both Jupyter notebook and JupyterLab. Either restart your kernel or run `alt.renderers.enable('default')` to restore the default.
3. The behavior above can happen if you have too old a version of IPython installed. See If the notebook displays on one laptop and not the other, it may be that the broken one has too old a version of IPython installed. See https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#notebook-textual-chart-representation for more information on what to upgrade.

See Altair's [Display Troubleshooting](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/troubleshooting.html) guide for more information.